# adding search bar to the nav menu in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, search, nav

http://www.lundarienpress.com/  ( this is a wordpress site)

This is my site, I am trying to add a search bar to the nav menu and have it to the right. Any ideas ?

I have not found a way to do it. I am hoping some one from the forum can help me.

Comment: share what you have tried. then if you got stucked with some exact issue, we will help you. Refer these links for asking proper questions (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) , (http://stackoverflow.com//help/mcve) and (http://sscce.org)

Comment: I don't know how to do, I want some help from here.

Comment: I am using a plugin so all I have to do is style it.

Comment: You can also use this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/add-search-to-menu to achieve it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Function.php code:

```
function add_last_nav_item($items, $args) {
  if ('header_menu' === $args->menu_id) {
        $homelink = get_search_form(false);
        $items .= '<li>'.$homelink.'</li>';
        return $items;
  }
  return $items;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_last_nav_item', 10, 2 );
```

Here `get_search_form()` is function to get search box.

Comment: should I add this to the function.php file  ?

Comment: ya, you can add this in function.php file.

Comment: you welcome, approve valid response. It's helpful to other peoples.

Comment: This shouldn't actually work properly, you need to set the get_search_form() to false for this to produce the proper markup.

Answer (score 12):

@rockmandew is right - this code shouldn't work without setting get_search_form() to false. But even after making that change, the function wouldn't work.

I initially added a search form to my nav menu by adding this to my functions file:

```
/**
 * Add search box to nav menu
 */
function wpgood_nav_search( $items, $args ) {
    $items .= '<li>' . get_search_form( false ) . '</li>';
    return $items;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items','wpgood_nav_search', 10, 2 );
```

This is a good solution if you have one menu or want a search box added to all menus. In my case, I only wanted to add a search box to my main menu. To make this happen, I went with this:

```
/**
 * Add search box to primary menu
 */
function wpgood_nav_search($items, $args) {
    // If this isn't the primary menu, do nothing
    if( !($args->theme_location == 'primary') ) 
    return $items;
    // Otherwise, add search form
    return $items . '<li>' . get_search_form(false) . '</li>';
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'wpgood_nav_search', 10, 2);
```

It's worth noting my main nav is named 'primary' in my functions file. This can vary by theme, so this would need to be changed accordingly, i.e. 'main' or as in the initial solution, 'header_menu'.

Comment: On twenty seventeen it's called 'top', took me a whole hour to find out.

Answer (score 0):

Both answers got me on the right path, but it seems the value of `args` depends on Wordpress version (I run 5.5), or theme (I am using https://underscores.me/ ) or whatever else (not the super WP expert here, just starting to dig into such WP topics).

What helps if the above does not work for you is to dump out `args` and modify the code accordingly.

Value of `args` for me:

```
stdClass::__set_state(array( 'menu' => WP_Term::__set_state(array( 'term_id' => 7, 'name' => 'Menu 1', 'slug' => 'menu-1', 'term_group' => 0, 'term_taxonomy_id' => 7, 'taxonomy' => 'nav_menu', 'description' => '', 'parent' => 0, 'count' => 5, 'filter' => 'raw', )), 'container' => 'div', 'container_class' => '', 'container_id' => '', 'container_aria_label' => '', 'menu_class' => 'menu', 'menu_id' => 'primary-menu', 'echo' => true, 'fallback_cb' => 'wp_page_menu', 'before' => '', 'after' => '', 'link_before' => '', 'link_after' => '', 'items_wrap' => '
%3$s
', 'item_spacing' => 'preserve', 'depth' => 0, 'walker' => '', 'theme_location' => 'menu-1', ))
```

So I went for checking `taxonomy` (also cleaned up the code a bit):

```
function add_last_nav_item($items, $args) {
    // just to show you how to dump it out - remove that line afterwards ofcs
    var_export($args);

    // If this is the menu you are looking for, add search form
    if (isset($args->menu->taxonomy) && $args->menu->taxonomy === 'nav_menu') {
        $items .= '<li>' . get_search_form(false) . '</li>';
    }
    return $items;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_last_nav_item', 10, 2);
```