# How to add the search bar to mobile menu in wordpress?

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress, searchbar

I've added this code to my functions.php file:

```
function wpgood_nav_search( $items, $args ) {
$items .= '<li>' . get_search_form( false ) . '</li>';
return $items;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items','wpgood_nav_search', 10, 2 );
```

I've found it here:
[adding search bar to the nav menu in wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31822842/adding-search-bar-to-the-nav-menu-in-wordpress)

The problem: this code adds the search bar to desktop and mobile menus, but I need to add the search bar **only to my mobile menu**, because the desktop version of my site already has a search widget in the left sidebar.

How can I do this? Please, help me. Thanks!

Initializiation of my menus in functions.php :

```
// Initialize navigation menus
register_nav_menus(
    array(
        'primary-menu' => esc_html__( 'Primary Menu', 'bento' ),
        'footer-menu' => esc_html__( 'Footer Menu', 'bento' ),
    )
);
```

***Thank you so much for your help! Finally I have decided to use my initial code and edit the searchbar's position and style with css, because I am not so good in coding:)***

Answer (score 1):

Basically do you do that by several process. Like following

- By using jquery append function you can do. Paste this code in template JS file

  ```html
  $("here_put_menu_selector").append('
  <li>
  <form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="search-form" action="https://yourdomain.com/">
   <div class="search-form-wrap"> 
    <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" class="search-form-input" placeholder="search any"/> 
    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" class="button submit-button" value="Search"/>
   </div>
  </form>
  </li>
  ');
  ```

Only on mobile devices visible that using CSS display property & hide that part from desktop/tablet devices.

Answer (score 0):

Use the javascript code for adding the search box for mobile menu

```
$("ul.primary-mobile-menu').append('
// your html code to append
<li><form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="search-form" action="https://bookyspace.com/"><div class="search-form-wrap"> <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" class="search-form-input" placeholder="Знайти.."> <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" class="button submit-button" value=""></div></form></li>
');
```

Thanks

Comment: Does not work, mobile menu becomes unclickable, I see chaos in header of desktop menu :( thank you for your reply

Answer (score 0):

@Vladislav Tiaglo

Add a class in the li item to the code you already used and said it´s working for both desktop and mobile:

```
<li> Add class to <li class="searchbox-position">
```

Then, in your css you code to hide the display for desktop:

```
@media (min-width: 840px) {
li.searchbox-position {
    display: none !important;
}
}
```

Easiest way to make it work